Can an argument be true while having logical errors?
When I was reading about the skepticism of logic, I found an interesting sylogism like this :
"If old TVs are white and black, and all penguins are also white and black, then all penguins are old TVs".
This makes me wonder why a valid deduction can lead to an absurd conclusion?
So I think, even if an argument is a valid deduction, it doesnt mean the argument is true.
So how about the other way around? I mean, is it possible an invalid deduction of argument to be true? Since I seek an explanation of informal fallacy itself say it happens because of the nature of language, not because the object of the argument is false.
Lets say for example, I said males are more rational than females, because Science shows to me that the way male brains work is different from the way female brains work, so I can conclude males are more rational because the way they are.
But this conclusion is claimed as "Ought-Is Fallacy".

But the argument above is not valid

A valid argument will only produce a true conclusion if all the premises are also true.

The problem with your TV/penguin argument is that you're misunderstanding "is". In these sentences, it doesn't mean "equivalent to", it means "has the quality". When we say that a house is white, it doesn't mean that the house is equivalent to all white things.

If I'm understanding correctly, you understand that the "penguins and TVs" example is a mistake in deduction that leads to a wrong conclusion. But you're curious if it's possible for an improper sequence of deductions can lead to a true conclusion, even if the reasoning is wrong?

The premises and conclusion of an argument can be true or false. The argument itself can be valid or invalid. What a valid argument rules out is true premises and a false conclusion. Any other combination is possible. You can have a valid argument with true premises and a true conclusion, or false premises and a true conclusion, or false premises and a false conclusion. An invalid argument can have any combination, and may have a true conclusion.

As far as i know, a conclusion in propositional logic is valid if the conclusion necessarily follows from the premises, in other words an conclusion valid if it is coherence with the premise. So in here, i doubt that conclusion of "Tv and Penguins" are invalid because i dont see any contradiction between that.

How is this different from:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/120234/is-it-possible-for-an-argument-to-be-illogical-and-yet-represent-a-completely-va ?

It's OK to say an argument is valid if the conclusion necessarily follows from the premises. But that is very different from saying that the conclusion is coherent (consistent) with the premises. The penguin argument is not valid.

This unfortunately mixes a lot of terminology.
So a deductive argument tries to infer a conclusion from a set of premises. So usually the first premise is a general rule, the second premise is a particular example and the conclusion is what comes out if you apply the general rule to the particular example.
So:
Premise 1: All birds can fly.
Premise 2: A Penguin is a bird.
-> Conclusion: A penguin can fly.

Now such an argument would be called valid, if and only if true premises MUST result in a true conclusion.
So in this case the argument is valid, because if it were indeed true that all birds can fly, and if it were further true that a penguin is a bird, then it MUST also be true that a penguin can fly. If a penguin couldn't fly then either he is no bird or not all birds can fly. But that would mean that one of the premises were to be false. So validity is just about the structure of the argument that indicates that if the premises are true, so is the conclusion.
Now as we all know penguins are the famously flightless birds, hence the first premise isn't actually true. So despite the argument being valid it is not sound. Where soundness is validity plus true premises (and because of that true conclusion as well).
Now it's quite important to note what that means and what it does not mean. For example a failure of soundness does not mean that the conclusion is false. Or in reverse:
Premise 1: All birds can fly.
Premise 2: A sparrow is a bird.
-> Conclusion: A sparrow can fly.

Now this argument suffers from the same logical error that in fact not all birds can fly, but the sparrow happens to be one of those birds than can actually fly, so just because the final statement is actually correct, does not mean that the argument is sound. So just because the statement is valid and the conclusion is true does not mean that the statement is sound.
So the classical error in deductive reasoning that all other fallacies are a subset of is "non sequitur" or "does not follow".
So it doesn't suffice that the rule works sometimes or even most of the times, it MUST work ALWAYS. Because if it does work always you can thus follow that it also works in the particular case, in any other case you could only say that with more or less probability but not with certainty.
Now if we take a look at your example:
Premise 1: (All) Old TVs are white and black
Premise 2: All penguins are also white and black
Conclusion: All penguins are old TVs

Then this is not valid. The conclusion does not follow from the premises. The problem being that just because all members of a group have a particular property, having that property doesn't indicate membership as also non-members can have that property.
So essentially the premise has it backwards. While for example:
Premise 1: (All) things white and black are old TVs
Premise 2: All penguins are also white and black
Conclusion: All penguins are old TVs

Would be similarly nonsense, but this time the nonsense would at least be deductively valid. If these premises would be true, the conclusion would also be true, but obviously they AREN'T true, so the conclusion doesn't have to be true. Again it can be true:
Premise 1: (All) Old TVs are white and black
Premise 2: All penguins are also white and black
Conclusion: All penguins are birds.

But the truths of the "conclusion" is not the result of inference from the premises it's just artificially appended.
Furthermore your example commits a fallacy of equivocation. That is you use the same word or the same idiom, in that case "white and black" (though I'd rather write black and white, but anyway), but you refer to two different concepts with it. In the case of the TV you refer to the images they can display (actually often enough TVs used to be brownish fitting into a wooden cabinet or whatnot. While in terms of the penguin it refers to their skin color and appearance. So you're not even comparing the same property, making the conclusion even more far fetched. So it's possible to create arguments that appear to be valid, but when further investigated turn out not to be valid because the words are used with different meanings and the conclusion doesn't actually follow if you tie them down to either one of the meanings.
So idk:
Premise 1: A star is a giant gassy object
Premise 2: [Insert celebrity] is a star
Conclusion: [Insert celebrity] is a giant gassy object

The structure seems technically valid and with the premises and the conclusions being true on their own, it also seems sound, BUT if you either used [hot celestial object] in both places or [celebrity] in both places of "star" you'd quickly realize that it is not actually a valid inference.
Now your last example
Premise 1: males are more rational than females
Premise 2: Science shows to me that the way male brains work is different 
Conclusion: males are more rational 

Now there's a lot of things wrong with that argument. Like so far I've just taken the 3 sentences and tried to fit them in the premise, premise, conclusion scheme, but as you see that doesn't work.
For example Premise 1 isn't actually a premise but just the conclusion... Premise 2 is also not really a premise and is not connected to either Premise 1 or the conclusion. So no the conclusion does not follow from the premises. Also "science shows" is an appeal to authority as that's essentially saying "I'm smart" rather than actually saying something that is smart. So if anything it obfuscates the actual argument and does not serve as replacement.
And last but not least there's the irony if a man is making that statement ;)

In Boolean logic, "x implies y" is defined as exactly equal to "x is false, or y is true". Or, not exclusive or. If X is false,  the implication statement is true/correct no matter what value Y takes.
This directly models "if x then y", which likewise says nothing about what happens to y when x is false.

Okay, so imagine this: you're trying to get to your friend's house. You have a map, but it's like, from the Middle Ages and totally wrong. You wander around, get lost, ask a squirrel for directions, and somehow, by sheer dumb luck, stumble onto your friend's doorstep. You got there, right? The conclusion (you're at your friend's house) is true. But the way you got there? Total garbage. That's what it's like when an argument has logical errors but a true conclusion.
In logic-land, there's a difference between validity and soundness. Validity is like having the right directions if the map was accurate. Your penguin argument? Valid structure, but the "map" (the premises) is bonkers. Penguins aren't TVs! Soundness means you have both the right directions and an accurate map.
Then there's informal fallacies. These are like getting lost because you asked a squirrel for directions. Your male/female rationality example is like that. Even if there are brain differences (and that's a big "if"), saying that automatically makes one gender "more rational" is a leap of logic. It's like saying squirrels are good at giving directions because they have bushy tails.
So, even if your conclusion happens to be true (like you finding your friend's house), if your reasoning is flawed, the argument itself is weak. It doesn't prove anything. It's just lucky. You might as well have flipped a coin.

The argument is invalid, not unsound. It instantiates the form: All A's are C's; all B's are C's; therefore all A's are B's.
